# Value in numpy array doesn't change when +=

Tags: python, numpy

I'm quite confused as to why the values in my numpy array don't change when i use `+=` on it, but do when i use `-=`. I've already checked using `-= -(speed * dt)` as well as `trying dims[1] = (speed * dt) + dims[1]` but it still doesn't seem to work.

It also doesn't raise an error, just doesn't change the value.

Here's my code (I'm on ubuntu):

```
import pygame
import threading
import numpy as np

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1420, 720])

playerdims = np.array([500, 200, 50, 80])
wasd = np.zeros((4, 1), dtype=bool)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

movspeed = 5
dt = 0

def updatedims(dims = playerdims, speed = movspeed, event = None):
        
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            wasd[0] = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            wasd[1] = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            wasd[2] = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            wasd[3] = True
            
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            wasd[0] = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            wasd[1] = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            wasd[2] = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            wasd[3] = False
            
    if wasd[0]:
        dims[1] -= (speed * dt)
    if wasd[1]:
        dims[0] -= (speed * dt)
    if wasd[2]:                    
        dims[1] += (speed * dt)   # doesn't change here
    if wasd[3]:
        dims[0] += (speed * dt)   # and here
        
while True:
    
    screen.fill('black')
    
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=updatedims, args=(playerdims, movspeed, ev), daemon=False)
        thread1.start()
        
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'red', (tuple(playerdims[:2]), tuple(playerdims[2:])))
    
    thread1.join()
    
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000
```

Comment: You absolutely don't need threads here, nor Numpy! For one, you're now reading the data before it may have had a chance to update (your draw code is before the join).

Comment: Please reduce the code to a [mre]. There are tons of parts unrelated to "value in numpy array doesn’t change" which both obscure what goes on and makes it harder for us - and you - to detect the error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version that doesn't mess around with Numpy or threads for no good reason.

You might want to consider Numpy when you have, say, lots of particles or whatnot you'd want to update quickly, but that would be something to consider only in the future.

Furthermore, threads are pretty tricky to work with; your original code spawns a new thread (which isn't necessarily lightweight) for each event in the Pygame event loop, and only ever waits for one of them to finish (with `.join()`), and even that only happens *after* you've drawn something.

```
import pygame

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1420, 720])
playerdims = [500, 200, 50, 80]
wasd = {
    pygame.K_w: False,
    pygame.K_a: False,
    pygame.K_s: False,
    pygame.K_d: False,
}
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
dt = 0
speed = 25

while True:

    # Read events and key state
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # If this is a key event...
        if event.type in (pygame.KEYDOWN, pygame.KEYUP):
            # If this key is in `wasd`, update it
            if event.key in wasd:
                wasd[event.key] = (
                    event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN
                )
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()

    # Update position
    if wasd[pygame.K_w]:
        playerdims[1] -= speed * dt
    if wasd[pygame.K_a]:
        playerdims[0] -= speed * dt
    if wasd[pygame.K_s]:
        playerdims[1] += speed * dt
    if wasd[pygame.K_d]:
        playerdims[0] += speed * dt

    # Update screen
    screen.fill("black")
    pygame.draw.rect(
        screen,
        "red",
        (tuple(playerdims[:2]), tuple(playerdims[2:])),
    )
    pygame.display.flip()
    dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000
```